# Facebook oauth 2.0 invite friends feature

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

I'm planning go implement the new oauth 2 login which will give me app scoped facebook ids instead of the real facebook user id.
My question is how to implement invite friends feature which will reward the users which invited friends (after the friends join my site).
With the old oauth 1 I would store the invitor id and invited id and when the invited user joins - I simply reward the user who invited him..but with the new auth I can't compare friend ID to app scoped user id.

Any suggestions how can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't incentivise people to invite their friends, unfortunately it's against [Facebook's policies (4.5)](https://developers.facebook.com/policy):

> Only incentivize a person to log into your app, like your app’s Page, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other actions. (Effective November 5th, 2014, you may no longer incentivize people to like your app's Page).

Comment: What if I make fb app for this purpose ? App where people go and invite friends using game requests (my site is gaming portal) ? The invited people then join the app and the app rewards the invitors.

Comment: This is and always has been a grey area. I'd recommend you do some research on what other firms have done in the past as an indicator of what is acceptable. Just be aware that you run a very real risk of Facebook banning your app, because they hate spam.